# dot product of two vectors in python 3 with out using the sum or zip function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code that checks that the length of two vectors matches and if so it computes the dot product of the two vectors. I'm getting the vector multiplication as my output but I need to sum them to obtain the dot product. I do not want to use the sum function to do so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
def dot(vector01,vector02):
    result= []
    if len(vector01) != len(vector02):
        raise ValueError
        for i in range(len(vector01)):
            total = 0
            total += vector01[i] * vector02[i]
            result.append(total)
       return result

vector01 = [2, 3, 4]
vector02 = [4, 2, 1]
print(dot(vector01,vector02))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dot product is a scalar number. You can change the code as following.

```
def dot(vector01, vector02):
    if len(vector01) != len(vector02):
        raise ValueError
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(vector01)):
        total += vector01[i] * vector02[i]
    return total
```

Comment: thank you for your help! very helpful!